# Multi-select in the prompt is not working properly in Cognos 8.1

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

Changing a value prompt to a multi-select value prompt in Report studio, provide single select functionality. How can i get multi-select functionality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at the parameter associated with the prompt. Now go look and see how you use that parameter to filter the queries in your report. If you have the filter set as:-

[namespace].[table].[column] = ?MyParameter?

... then it doesn't matter that your prompt is a multi-select prompt, it will still run as a single selection prompt. Modify your filters so they are of the form:-

[namespace].[table].[column] in ?MyParameter?

This tells Cognos that your parameter can contain multiple values, and it will display the prompt accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer. If the prompt is embedded in the QuerySubject in your Framework, you may need to check the Query Subject and see if it uses #promptmany()# macro instead of #prompt#.